# E763 with vim and spell checker

Tags: vim, spell-checking

I want to add germand spell checking to vim. So I set

```
:set spl=de_de spell
```

then there is a dialogue, where I can create a directory called `.vim/spell`. And then there is another question where I can download a `.spl` file. And again for a `.sug` file. But when I download both files I get an error

```
Fehler beim Ausführen von "~/.vim/spell/de.utf-8.spl":
E763: 'Word Characters' unterscheiden sich zwischen Rechtschreibwörterbüchern
```

But despite the error I can use the spell checking and even the suggestion works.

Also I could not `:mksp` my own `.spl`-file from myspell, cause it wouldn't read the `.dic`-file. And I deleted the `spell`directory and retried it. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian wheezy:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-scripts # Needed for spell downloading script
sudo rm /usr/share/vim/vim73/spell/*.sug /usr/share/vim/vim73/spell/*.spl
sudo vim
```

now trigger downloading in `vim`:

```
set spell spelllang=en,de,OR_WHATEVER_LANGUAGE_YOU_WANT
```

et voilà, you will get perfectly working spell files for all users.

(If you only want them for the current user, skip the `sudo` before calling vim or, change the installation directory to `/home/YOUR_USER/.vim/spell`.)

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! So there seems to be a conflict between the already installed (Fedora Linux) en.spl or en.sug files with the downloaded german/spanish/… files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (same errormessage) and I guess, it was due to a compatibility-problem.  The spell files I used (installed in .vim/spell) were from an older installation of vim and when I updated vim, I got this error.  I solved it by using the vim spell files provided by my distribution -- in my case Arch Linux

```
sudo pacman -S vim-spell-de
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such packet for ubuntu.

Comment: had the same message, this helped. when moving from ubuntu to arch I had simply copied my old spell files. after removing .vim/spell, the message disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a self-compiled Vim 7.3.729 on Windows/x64. As the spell files at http://ftp.vim.org/vim/runtime/spell/de/ haven't been updated yet, I solved this in the following way:

1. download the Arch Linux package mentioned in skunk's answer from https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/vim-spell-de/
2. Extract the spell files from the `vim-spell-de-20120506-1-any.pkg.tar.xz` file (*7Zip* can unpack them).
3. Overwrite the 4 files `de.{latin1,utf-8}.{spl.sug}` in `~/.vim/spell/`